# match two Arrays and keep order of both equal

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have two arrays with the same length, but not entirely the same data as follows:

```
Array1: [{name: john, num: 030}, {name: david, num: 130}, {name: john, num: 200}, {name: jane, num: 500}]
Array2: [{name: john, num: 030}, {name: david, num: 130}, {name: jane, num: 500}, {name: '', num: ''}]
```

Array2 only has element where num matches Array1 num

Is there a way to make sure that these two arrays match their indexes even if the data does not match

for example, their index will look like this

```
Array1: [{name: john, num: 030}, {name: david, num: 130}, {name: john, num: 200}, {name: jane, num: 500}]
Array2: [{name: james, num: 030}, {name: frank, num: 130}, {name: '', num: ''},  {name: kate, num: 500},]
```

This means they match by index, and order is maintained.
The main goal is that Array2 maintains the order of Array1.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? of the two arrays and the mapping. I have a feeling that there's a better data-structure for this.

Comment: and avoid [octal number literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#octal_numbers) `num: 030`. Depending on the digits, they will be parsed either as octal **or** as decimal.

Comment: @Thomas.. I used sheetjs library to add reading and writing to excel functionality to my react project but I am trying add a functionality where the data is read from the excel file and converted to json, then it is matched to data from another excel file and then written to that excel file.

Comment: @Thomas.. Noted on the octal number literals

Comment: @Thomas..The order I am trying to achieve is mainly to make make sure Array2 is writing to the excel workbook in the other of Array1. Array1 is mainly showing me the order to write Array2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the description seen in the question, list two logics

1. The value of attribute num is unique in each array
2. The only exception is an empty string

I implemented it according to the above logic, you can see if it helps you, if the logic does not meet your actual needs, you can provide more details and clear logic, I will adjust it

```js
const array1 = [{name: 'john', num: '030'}, {name: 'david', num: '130'}, {name: 'john', num: '200'}, {name: 'jane', num: '500'}];

let array2 = [{name: 'david', num: '130'}, {name: 'jane', num: '500'}, {name: 'john', num: '030'}, {name: '', num: ''}];

const originalLength = array2.length;
const originalArr = array2.slice(0, originalLength);
array2.length = originalLength * 2;

const provide = (arr, field, index) => {
  let result = arr.filter(a => a[field] == array1[index][field]);
  if(result.length == 0){
    result = arr.filter(a => a[field] == '');
  }
  return result[0];
};

for(let i=0; i<array1.length ; i++)
{
  const item = provide(originalArr, 'num', i);
  array2[i] = item;
}

array2.length = originalLength;
console.log(JSON.stringify(array2));
```